# kth largest element in range interval

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of overlapping intervals of integers. I need to find the **kth** largest element.

Example:

```
List { (3,4), (2,8), (4,8), (1,3), (7,9) }
```

This interval represents numbers as

```
[3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3], and [7, 8, 9].
```

If we merge and sort it in decreasing order, we get

```
9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1
```

Now the 4th largest number in the list is 8.

Can anyone please explain an **efficient** (we don't have to generate the list) algorithm to find the kth element given only a list of internals ?

Comment: Do we assume that there are no gaps? That is, could we have `{ [3, 4], [100, 108] }`?

Comment: An interval { 3,4 } means numbers from 3 to 4 and { 100, 108 } means elements starting from 100 to 108.

Comment: I know what the intervals mean. I wanted to make sure not to assume that, combined, it is not necessarily one contiguous interval.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out the largest number. You go through intervals and examine ends of intervals. In your case it is 9. Set `k = 1`, and `L = 9`.
2. Perhaps there are other 9s. Mark `(7,9)` interval as visited and check if any other intervals contains 9 `a >= 9 && b <= '`. In your case there is only one 9.
3. Decrement current largest number (`L -= L`) and clear history of visited intervals. And repeat checking intervals.
4. Every time you meet your current largest number within an interval you should increment `k` and mark the interval as visited. As soon as it becomes equal to `kth` the current greatest number `L` is your answer.